# error: extraneous input '.' expecting {, in Android Room Query

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

Using below query in Android Room :

```
 @Query(
     "SELECT strftime ('%d-%m-%Y', datetime(DISTINCT timeStamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) AS e.name " +
             "FROM (SELECT batteryDetails.*, " +
             "COUNT(logId) OVER" +
             "(PARTITION BY batteryId) AS oldStatus " +
             "from batteryDetails) batteryDetails " +
             "LEFT JOIN eventTypes e ON e.eventType = batteryDetails.status " +
             "WHERE oldStatus is null OR oldStatus <> status AND batteryId = :batteryId AND " +
             "timeStamp between :startDate AND :endDate " +
             "ORDER BY timeStamp DESC"
 )
suspend fun getHistoryEventsData(
    batteryId: String,
    startDate: String,
    endDate: String
): List<String>?
```

**getHistoryEventsData** is a function

This Query is running successfully in SQLite db browser.

But it giving me below error while running app :

> error: extraneous input '.' expecting {, ';', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH, K_DROP, K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_INSERT, K_PRAGMA, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}
> public abstract java.lang.Object getHistoryEventsData(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
> ^
> extraneous input '(' expecting {, ';', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, K_ATTACH, K_BEGIN, K_COMMIT, K_CREATE, K_DELETE, K_DETACH, K_DROP, K_END, K_EXPLAIN, K_INSERT, K_PRAGMA, K_REINDEX, K_RELEASE, K_REPLACE, K_ROLLBACK, K_SAVEPOINT, K_SELECT, K_UPDATE, K_VACUUM, K_VALUES, K_WITH, UNEXPECTED_CHAR}

What might be the Issue?

My SQLite version is 3.28.0 and using roomRuntime=3.2.0

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 syntactical errors in your query.

The 1st is the use of the keyword `DISTINCT` inside the function `strftime()` (this is actually allowed by SQLite but does not behave like it should). Maybe you want it before the function.
The 2nd is that you use the alias `e` to qualify the name of the column alias `name` in its definition. The definition of an alias should not be qualified.

Change to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%d-%m-%Y', datetime(timeStamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')) AS name 
FROM (
  SELECT batteryDetails.*, 
         COUNT(logId) OVER(PARTITION BY batteryId) AS oldStatus 
  from batteryDetails
) batteryDetails 
LEFT JOIN eventTypes e ON e.eventType = batteryDetails.status 
WHERE oldStatus is null OR oldStatus <> status 
  AND batteryId = :batteryId 
  AND timeStamp between :startDate AND :endDate 
ORDER BY timeStamp DESC;
```

Also, this:

```
strftime('%d-%m-%Y', datetime(timeStamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'))
```

could be simplified to:

```
strftime('%d-%m-%Y', timeStamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime')
```

Comment: @JaiminModi also, I think that you should enclose `oldStatus is null OR oldStatus <> status` inside parentheses, because the operator AND has higher precedence than OR (this is not a syntactical error).

Comment: okay I will inform here once I will do it. Currently It was displaying the same.